# Does anyone know a way of getting a list or number of errors before the build process is complete

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

Our build process deploys our product to a remote instance for testing and sends a custom email to our entire dev team notifying them if it was successful.

Right now I have a custom activity that uses the BuildDetails.CompilationStatus and the BuildDetails.TestStatus to determine if there were any errors in the build process.

Is there anyway to get the specific errors from build process?

Comment: Unrelated to your question (but I am curious): Are you using the Test Controller/Test Agent mechanisms to deploy your builds or are you using an entirely custom method?

Comment: Read the build log and search for lines with FAILED in it, in another custom activity.

Comment: I am using a lot of custom powershell scripts that use the AWS API to upload our program to S3 and a separate powershell script to create EC2 instances and a CloudFormation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code actually ended up doing what I wanted and I was able to go through each of the errors and warnings and add them to my email output.

```
List<IBuildError> builderrors = InformationNodeConverters.GetBuildErrors(buildDetails);
List<IBuildWarning> buildwarnings = InformationNodeConverters.GetBuildWarnings(buildDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a custom msbuild logger and get all the errors/warnings/messages.

Edit:

[Logging in MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
[Build loggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171471.aspx)